# arm bit extraction and logical shift confusion

Tags: assembly, arm

```
.set AD0GDR,        0xE0034004 
... 
bitextract: .int 65472
...
 LDR r3, =(AD0GDR)
 LDR r4, [r3]
 /*load #65472 into r5 that will be used to extract bits 6-15*/
 LDR r5, =(bitextract)  
 ADD r6, r4, r5 // extracts bits 6-15 and stores into r6
 ADD r0, r0, r6, LSR #15 // shift r6 bites off and add into r0
```

I am new to ARM and can not find an exact answer anywhere. 
I'm trying to extract only a certain number of bits from some data that I'm being given, specifically the bits 6-15. The decimal number for bits 6-15 is 65427.

From prior thoughts, adding 65472 to the value that I'm given, in this case AD0GDR which is 3758309380, is 3758374852.

Now, my understanding is that in binary equivalent of the answer, by adding 65472 it will put "1's" in bits 6-15. However, that is not true. So what is happening by adding 65427 to the value given?
Edit: I guess a better question is why does adding 65472 extract bits 6-15? or if it doesn't, what exactly is happening.

And my second question refers to the LSR.

The reason I ask the question before is because I'm required to "Extract the pure sample from bits 6:15 and shift it all the way to the right of the register." and add that value to a different register. Should I be shifting the last 15 bits off of the register? I guess I'm confused by the wording in this situation.

Comment: Your teacher apparently stopped programming at armv5. Newer arm architectures feature instructions like ubfx that will single handedly do the job.

Answer (score 2):

Consider smaller values:

```
   000 101 xxx        000 010 xxx        000 000 xxx 
 + 000 111 000      + 000 111 000     +  000 111 000
--------------   vs. ------------   vs. ------------
     1 100 xxx          1 001 xxx          0 111 xxx
```

Which means, that value + mask >> n, extracts 0, if the value is 0 and 1, if the value was non-zero. The prerequisite being that there are no non-zero bits to the left of the value of interest. One possible explanation is, that the operation discussed really was AND instead of ADD.

**EDIT**: Even though adding the mask results in a half carry, this is not, what the LSR #15 extracts; The carry (i.e the expression (bitfield != 0)) can be added with expression `add r0,r0,r6 LSR #16`

Instead, two bits are added, Carry with weight 2, and the "new sign bit of expression (bitfield - 1)". Or in tabular form:

```
BF    as int    C  BF+M   LSR #2
000 = 0 (0)     (0) 111    + 1
001 = 1 (1)     (1) 000    + 2
010 = 2 (2)     (1) 001    + 2
011 = 3 (3)     (1) 010    + 2
100 = 4 (-4)    (1) 011    + 2
101 = 5 (-3)    (1) 100    + 3
110 = 6 (-2)    (1) 101    + 3
111 = 7 (-3)    (1) 110    + 3
```

I'm afraid, but I can't find a reason to do that from the field of sampling theorem or DSP.

Comment: I think he is confused about the purpose.  As you have shown, if any bit is set in the field, we will *carry out*.  The shift just normalize the carry out, so it can be added to `R0` as one or zero.

Comment: +1 for trying to address the most confusing part of the question (which I skirted around...)

Answer (score 1):

To get certain bits (regardless of platform) you typically will do a bitwise AND, followed by a logical shift.  In your case, bits 6 - 15 in hex are `0xFFCO`, and you need to shift right by 6 bits in the end (assuming you want your bits right- aligned in the end). That means you will want to do

```
(num & 0xFFC0) >> 6
```

You will need to translate that into your own language…

**EDIT** another way you can do this is first right-shift, then mask the bits you don't want:

```
(num >> 6) & 0x3FF
```

since you only want the bottom 10 bits, and want everything else to be zero.

To address your other question: "how does adding a number extract bits", the answer is "it doesn't". The `AND` operation is a logical (bitwise) operation, not an "addition". Simple example:

```
abcdefgh & 0x34 =
abcdefgh & 00111000b =
00cde000
```

In other words, the logical AND will preserve the bits `cde` in the number above, and set all the other bits to zero (in this particular example). I hope that makes things clearer for you.

Comment: According to my teacher's code, simply adding the bits 6-15 to a value of a certain data does something that allows me to only use only the 6-15 bits of that certain data. There is no need to do a logical shift in this situation, I'm just confused as to why it works. I've done a different lab that includes the same code I posted and it works wonders.

Comment: If you look at Aki's answer, you will see that adding the mask will allow you to test (in a single operation) whether one of the bits 6-15 is set (by testing for overflow if you were using 16 bit integers). But if you want to do something with all the bits, it's hard to see how ADD rather than AND gives the result you appear to be asking for.